# handling empty arrays in nested array

Tags: python, numpy, nested-lists

I need to do `dot product` on each pair of some arrays where there are some empty sub arrays, in different index . i,e

```
event1:
array([[  5.35375254e-07   6.40314998e-02], 0.159332022418, [],
       0.0396021990432, 0.00795516103045, 0.0457216188153, [],
       0.0331742073438], dtype=object)

event2:
array([[  5.97561615e-06   5.56173790e-02], 0.119262253938, [],
       0.161581488798, 0.00560146601083, 0.0735139212697, 0.0585291344263,
       0.177536950441], dtype=object)
```

as you can see I have some empty arrays in these arrays, so when I do the dot product,those empty arrays make everything to `[]`.

first of all I tried to the empty arrays and change them to zero but couldn't think of any solution better than looping through each element of arrays and change empty to zero.

is there any efficient way to do this?

Comment: can't you just use something like ```[i*j for i,j in zip(event1,event2) if i and j]``` or ```[i*j for i,j in zip(filter(None, event1), filter(None, event2))]``` depending on desired result

Comment: not really, I found the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I solved it using  numpy nonzero() method. It returns the index of nonzero/non_empty elements. i.e:

```
a = array([[5.97561615e-06, 0.055617379], 0.119262253938, [], 0.21321, []], dtype=object)

In [110]: a.nonzero()
Out[110]: (array([0, 1, 3]),)

non_empty= set(a.nonzero()[0])
complete_index = set(range(len(a)))
empty = list(complete - non_empty)
a[empty]= 0
In [130]: a
Out[130]: array([[5.97561615e-06, 0.055617379], 0.119262253938, 0, 0.21321, 0], dtype=object)
```

Comment: isn't it simpler to use ```array([f or 0 for f in ff])```

Comment: sorry but I can understand what you mean

Comment: this code does the same that your code does as i can see. ```a = array([f or 0 for f in a])```